# How secure is JavaScript encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm developing a web project using JavaScript with AJAX requests to WebServices and I'm interested in encrypting the information.

How secure is to encrypt from the client side? Remember that I'm not using a server side language.

Comment: If you encrypt something on the client side it makes sense that everyone can see that information as is, doesn't it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean ensuring the data is secure during transmission to the service? If so why not use https?

Comment: I'm using https connection but besides that I'm interested in encrypt data before sending it to the WebService.

Comment: This might be relevant, or at least interesting: https://github.com/GPGTools/Mobile/wiki/Introduction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [huge discussion on hackernews about this](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2935220) last week, inspired by this article on [matasano.com](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Basically, secure javascript does not exist. The only way is to have everything be over HTTPS, because if you don't, you expose your user to certain flaws.

But once you have HTTPS, extra encryption via javascript is pointless: everything already is secure.

Comment: I'll take a look in the articles, thanks. Why do you say that encryption is pointless when using https?

Comment: It's in the article: Why can't I use TLS/SSL to deliver the Javascript crypto code?

You can. It's harder than it sounds, but you safely transmit Javascript crypto to a browser using SSL. The problem is, having established a secure channel with SSL, **you no longer need Javascript cryptography; you have "real" cryptography**. Meanwhile, the Javascript crypto code is still imperiled by other browser problems.

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just have your connections be https instead of http?

Comment: I'm using https connection but besides that I'm interested in encrypt data before sending it to the WebService.

Comment: @Diogo: Encrypting things twice doesn't make them any safer.

Answer (score 1):

Not very secure. There are little tricks here and there that you can do to make it a bit more difficult to breach the security but in the end if you give both the key and lock away to the public then you're not really secure.